# Do you know the base of amcharts logarithmic scale?

Tags: amcharts4, natural-logarithm

I am porting a chart form Dundas to amCharts. This charts uses a logarithmic scale base on the natural log. It does not seem you can change the base of the scale in amcharts like you can in Dundas. Does anyone know what the base of the logarithmic scale is in amcharts. Is it natural log (2.7~) or base 10 log?